# Can an NSOpenPanel open with a package pre-selected rather than showing the contents of the package?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

I'm trying to show an NSOpenPanel with a file preselected.

I'm using

```
    openPanel.directoryURL = fileURL;
    [openPanel runModal];
```

to set the file (assume fileURL is a valid NSURL) and show the panel.

Things work great when the NSURL for the file references a "normal" file.  The Open Panel opens to the correct directory and selects the proper file.

Things don't work like I want when the NSURL references a package (such as an application bundle or a localized PDF).  In these situations, the NSOpenPanel opens to show the contents of the package rather than the directory that contains the package.

There are deprecated methods that I could use to open the panel properly (I think) but I'd rather avoid those.

Is there a way to open an NSOpenPanel with a package properly preselected using non-deprecated methods?

Comment: Have you called `setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories:NO` on the panel?